# Unable to create decrypt using base 64 key with node-jose

Tags: node.js, jwt, jwk

I am trying to use [the `node-jose` library](https://github.com/cisco/node-jose) to decrypt a JWE, but am running into issues using the base64 of a secret as a key (as an external API instructs me to do).

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const jose = require('node-jose');

const secret = 'mySecret';
let hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');
let data = hash.update(secret, 'utf-8');
let token = getToken(); // Token is a correctly formatted JWE
const key = JSON.stringify({ key: data.digest('base64'), kty: 'oct', alg: 'HS512', use: 'enc' });

jose.JWK.asKey(key).
  then(function (result) {

    jose.JWE.createDecrypt(result.keystore).
      decrypt(token).
      then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

This returns the following error:

`Error: no key found`

Am I doing something wrong in the initialization of the key? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working myself with the following:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const jose = require('node-jose');

const secret = 'mySecret';
let token = getToken(); // Token is a correctly formatted JWE

let keystore = jose.JWK.createKeyStore();

// *****The crucial bit*****
const bufferderived = crypto.createHash('sha512')
      .update(secret)
      .digest()
      .slice(0, 512 / 8);

keystore.add({
  k: bufferderived, 
  kty: 'oct',
  alg: 'dir'
})
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);

    jose.JWE.createDecrypt(keystore).
      decrypt(token).
      then(function (result) {
        const decryptedToken = result.plaintext.toString('utf8');
        const decoded = jwt.decode(decryptedToken);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  });
```